# Laravel ignores APP_URL for verifications email

Tags: php, laravel

Laravel 5.7, PHP 7.2, Mysql 5.7

API works on `api.example.com`

In `APP_URL` I set `example.com`

in a verification email, I received an email with URL `api.example.com`

- cache cleared
- no queue

I think the

```php
// Illuminate\Auth\Notification\VerifyEmail

URL::temporarySignedRoute
```

ignores `APP_URL`

BONUS:

in forgot password mail URL is OK,
when I type in `tinker`

```php
URL::temporarySignedRoute(
    'verification.verify', 
    \Illuminate\Support\Carbon::now()->addMinutes(60), 
    ['id' => 1234]
)
```

I see URL with `example.com` (yes, cache cleared, even project rebuilded from scratch)

Comment: What do you have in config/app.php for url variable?

Comment: 'url' => env('APP_URL', 'https://example.com') ofcourse

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: Laravel (5.7, 5.8) don't support correct email validation for applications based on REST API hosted on a different domain than a page to verify email.

To make it works You have to change a lot of dependencies, and it's also not so secure...

The best option is to create own verification flow (eg. separate table in DB) based at `users.email_veryfied_at` column to support `verify middleware`